# How can I write output result depending on two state of input

Tags: c++, if-statement

i am using `if` command to decide output from two input `A,B`  as the table

```
 A   B   write_output
 0   0   1 1
>0   0   0 1
 0  >0   1 0
>0  >0   0 0
```

For example, if A>0 and B=0 then i will write the output value as 0 and 1. I am using if command to implement it. But it was not my expected table. Could you help me to fix it

This is my code

```
std::ofstream myfile;
myfile.open ("report.txt", std::ios::app);  
if(A==0 & B==0)
   myfile <<  1 << "\t" <<1<<'\n';
else if (A>0)
   myfile << 0 << "\t" <<1<<'\n';
else if (B>0)
   myfile << 1 << "\t" <<0<<'\n';
else
   myfile << 0 << "\t" <<0<<'\n';
myfile.close();
```

The output in text file as

```
1   0
1   0
0   0
0   0
```

You can see that the second column almost is zero value. It that means the code did not go to else if(B>0).

Comment: You need to use `if(A==0 && B==0)` instead of `if(A==0 & B==0)`.

Comment: Typo. Use `if(A==0 && B==0)` instead of `if(A==0 & B==0)`.

Comment: `&` used in condition is bitwise AND , you need to use logical AND `&&` .

Comment: OP also needs to fully test the `A > 0 && B == 0` condition in the second if, and the `B > 0 && A == 0` condition in the third.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your logic is flawed. You need to test both conditions in all if branches. As it is currently written you can never reach the else part.

It should be:

```
if(A==0 && B==0)
   myfile << 1 << "\t" << 1 << '\n';
else if (A>0 && B==0)
   myfile << 0 << "\t" << 1 << '\n';
else if (A==0 && B>0)
   myfile << 1 << "\t" << 0 << '\n';
else
   myfile << 0 << "\t" << 0 << '\n';
```

Also, `&` is bitwise AND; you want `&&` for logic AND.